# How to show the equation by integrating by parts .

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n.}$ For $u \in C^1(\Omega) $ and $ \phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ one has

$\int_{\Omega}\nabla|u|\phi dx=-\int_{\Omega}|u|\nabla\phi dx$

Comment: Perhaps you could take the gradient of $|u| \phi$, and reintegrate both sides. Then use the definiting of a gradient vector field to conclude your result.

Comment: Approximate the absolute value by a smooth function, e.g., $t\mapsto\sqrt{t^2+\epsilon}$, use partial integration for the approximation, verify that in the limit $\epsilon\searrow0$ the desired equation appears